# UPDATE and INSERT should fire trigger only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Is there any way to combine an update and an insert statements in a way that they fires a trigger only once?

I have one particular table that has (and currently needs) a trigger `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`. Now I want to update one row and insert another row and have the trigger fire only once for that.

Is this at all possible?

I already tried a MERGE-Statement without success: The trigger fires once for the update- and once for the insert-part.

Comment: your best bet is to have some "flag" value that your insert and/or update puts in a column of the row so your second trigger call knows whats going on and acts appropriately.

Comment: You'll always have it fired twice. However, referential constraints (such as CHECK or FOREIGN KEY) would only be checked once after a `MERGE` - so if you could replace the trigger logic with referential constraints, your actual problem might be solvable. Impossible to say whether that's the case for you without knowing what the trigger is doing.

Comment: Thank you fo the answers. Constraints will definitely not work for me. One thing I remembered during lunch: all calls get access to all the data written, when using a select. While still not perfect, this is good enough for me.

Comment: Are you able to provide us with some sample data and a sample of how your trigger currently looks like? It's the only way we can find a solution, everything else is just assumption.

Comment: To SQL the update and insert are two statements.  The update does not even know the insert is coming.  The insert does not know it followed a paired update.  Drop the triggers and use stored procedures.

Comment: This is an extension to @KM's idea, if you think a flag might be a bit ugly, then you could could have audit columns, CreatedAt and LastModifiedAt, then just compare them to find out if its a create or an update

Answer (score 1):

Well, problem solved for me. I did NOT find a way to combine the statements into one fire-event of the trigger. But the trigger behaves in an interesting way, that was good enough for me: Both calls to the trigger do already have access to the fully updated data.

Just execute the following statements and you will see what I mean.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (V INT)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER tFoo ON Foo AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
  SELECT 'inserted' AS Type, * FROM inserted
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'deleted', * FROM deleted
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'actual', * FROM Foo
GO
DELETE FROM Foo
INSERT Foo VALUES (1)
;MERGE INTO Foo
  USING (SELECT 2 AS V) AS Source ON 1 = 0
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (V) VALUES (Source.V);
```

As a result, the trigger will be called twice for the MERGE. But both times, "SELECT * FROM Foo" delivers the fully updated data already: There will be one row with the value 2. The value 1 is deleted already.

This really surprised me: The insert-trigger is called first and the deleted row is gone from the data before the call to the delete-trigger happens.

Only the values of "inserted" and "deleted" correspond to the delete- or insert-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

The trigger would check for the existence of #temp table.

If it doesn't exist, it creates it with dummy data. It then checks if the recent values contain the same user (SPID) that is running now and if the last time it was triggered was within 20 seconds.

If these are true then it will `PRINT 'Do Nothing'` and drop the table, otherwise it will do your trigger statement.
At the end of your trigger statement it inserts into the table the SPID and current datetime.

This temp table should last as long as the SPID connection, if you want it to last longer make it a ##temp or a real table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NULL
begin
Create table #temp(SPID int, dt datetime)
insert into #temp values (0, '2000-01-01')
end

If @@SPID = (select top 1 SPID from #temp order by dt desc) 
and Convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(19),GETDATE(),121)) between 
Convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(19),(Select top 1 dt from #temp order by dt desc),121)) and 
Convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(19),DateAdd(second, 20, (select top 1 dt from #temp order by dt desc)),121))
    begin
    PRINT 'Do Nothing'
    Drop table #temp
    end
    else
    begin
    --trigger statement

    Insert into #temp values (@@SPID, GETDATE())
    end
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but it does not work for me, because I need to react on both, the inserted and the deleted table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean if you perform an update, insert and delete within seconds of each other you want the insert and update statement to only process once and the delete to process once?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this will ignore every second event that fires the trigger as long as it is from the same user and within 20s. Thus it would fail if merge-statements and normal statements are mixed when writing to the table, wouldn't it?

Comment: It does but you could just put in the statements that you want to fire once in this If clause and have statements you always want to fire outside of it.